# How to make a GDB breakpoint only break after the point is reached a given number times?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I have a function that is called some large number of times, and eventually segfaults.

However, I don't want to set a breakpoint at this function and stop after every time it's called, because I will be here for years.

I've heard that I can set a `counter` in GDB for a breakpoint, and each time the breakpoint is hit, the counter is decremented, and only gets triggered when the `counter` = 0.

Is this accurate, and if so how do I do it? Please give the gdb code for setting such a breakpoint.

Comment: FYI this is called a conditional breakpoint

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Read [section 5.1.6](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Conditions.html#Conditions) of the GDB manual. What you have to do is first set a breakpoint, then set an 'ignore count' for that breakpoint number, e.g. `ignore 23 1000`.

If you don't know how many times to ignore the breakpoint, and don't want to count manually, the following may help:

```
  ignore 23 1000000   # set ignore count very high.

  run                 # the program will SIGSEGV before reaching the ignore count.
                      # Once it stops with SIGSEGV:

  info break 23       # tells you how many times the breakpoint has been hit, 
                      # which is exactly the count you want
```

Comment: Note: for the example `ignore 23 1000`,  `23` is the breakpoint ID and  `1000` is how many times you want to ignore the breakpoint.

Answer (score 28):

**`continue <n>`**

This is a convenient method that skips the last hit breakpoint `n - 1` times (and therefore stops at the n-th hit):

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        i++; /* Line 6 */
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
gdb -n -q main.out
```

GDB session:

```
Reading symbols from main.out...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x6a8: file main.c, line 4.
Starting program: /home/ciro/bak/git/cpp-cheat/gdb/main.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           int i = 0;
(gdb) b 6
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5555555546af: file main.c, line 6.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at main.c:6
6               i++; /* Line 6 */
(gdb) c 5
Will ignore next 4 crossings of breakpoint 2.  Continuing.
1
2
3
4
5

Breakpoint 2, main () at main.c:6
6               i++; /* Line 6 */
(gdb) p i
$1 = 5
(gdb)
(gdb) help c
Continue program being debugged, after signal or breakpoint.
Usage: continue [N]
If proceeding from breakpoint, a number N may be used as an argument,
which means to set the ignore count of that breakpoint to N - 1 (so that
the breakpoint won't break until the Nth time it is reached).
```