# How to ask GDB to break at a function only after it's called certain times?

Tags: gdb

For example, I have a function NamespaceA::ClassB::FunctionC() in my program. I know I can ask GDB to break there, by "break NamespaceA::ClassB::FunctionC". But what should I do if I only want GDB to break there, after this function is called, say, 100 times?

I think a workaround solution is adding one more variable in the program, and then there is "break ... if cond" command in GDB i can use. But can i achieve the same thing without adding variables to my program?

Thank you.

Comment: see related question under
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956889/how-to-set-a-counter-for-a-gdb-breakpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a GDB breakpoint only break after the point is reached a given number times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956889/how-to-make-a-gdb-breakpoint-only-break-after-the-point-is-reached-a-given-numbe)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
(gdb) continue 100
```

should do the trick

```
(gdb) help continue
Continue program being debugged, after signal or breakpoint.
 If proceeding from breakpoint, a number N may be used as an argument,
 which means to set the ignore count of that breakpoint to N – 1 (so that
 the breakpoint won’t break until the Nth time it is reached).
```

Comment: This assumes that you're already at the given breakpoint. You can also set the ignore count directly with `ignore <n> <count>`, where `n` is the number of the breakpoint to ignore `count` times.

Comment: @Jefromi IMHO your comment is worth to become another answer.