# Using Tracepoints in GDB to track how often code is executed

Tags: gdb, trace

I want to count how often a certain function or line of code is executed during a test run.
My idea is to set a tracepoint using GDB at a line and then count how often the tracepoint is hit.
Can anyone tell me if/how this can be achieved.
The only functions I can find for tracepoints are to take snapshots of registers or to save the values of variables. I think my answer might be related to the passcount value, but I don't know how to implement what I want.

If more info or detail is needed, please let me know,

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set a 'counter' for a GDB breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956889/how-to-set-a-counter-for-a-gdb-breakpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956889/how-to-set-a-counter-for-a-gdb-breakpoint) provides a very nice trick to get the count. I think this will solve your problem without ambiguity.
HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used tracepoints, but you can achieve the same using breakpoints.
Just define a breakpoint and afterwards define a command like this

```
command <breakpoint no.>
  continue
end
```

This will cause GDB to simply continue after the breakpoint is hit, but it still increase the hit counter. Note that this will significantly slow down your process.
Another option would be to valgrind (the callgrind subcommand), if you are on Linux.