# How can I make gdb stop at the breakpoint after loop has been executed n number of times

Tags: debugging, loops, for-loop, gdb

I want to stop the execution, when the loop has been executed n number of times. I don't want to use the conditional breakpoint using value of loop-counter because initial value of loop-counter is different at different time of run.

Comment: Will this do what you want? [stackoverflow.com: how to set a 'counter' for a GDB breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956889/how-to-set-a-counter-for-a-gdb-breakpoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `ignore` command.  Set a breakpoint at the relevant place in your loop and then use `ignore` to indicate how many times that the breakpoint is to be ignored.

Syntax, as per `help ignore` is:

> Set ignore-count of breakpoint number N to COUNT. Usage is `ignore N
>   COUNT'.