# gdb - perform a command n times

Tags: gdb

I am using the gdb debugger to run a program that has a loop in it (let's sat of 10).
When I get to the loop, I don't want to go into it. I know I can make a second breakpoint after the loop and than do c (continue). But I also remember there is a possibility to do something like n 10 (next 10 times). n 10 doesn't work (gdb doesn't say I've done something wrong, but it doesn't do what I am expecting).

Is it possible to run a command n times?

Answer (score 12):

To perform any gdb command N times, the easiest way is:

```
(gdb) python [gdb.execute('YOUR_COMMAND') for x in range(N)]
```

It can be very helpful for your custom gdb commands (see gdb define)

For example,

```
(gdb) python [gdb.execute('next') for x in range(10)]
(gdb) python [gdb.execute('step') for x in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Do you know the command `until`?

Try use it to go until line X.

Example:

```
(gdb) until 123
```

or

```
(gdb) u 123
```

> `(gdb) help until`
>
> Execute until the program reaches a source line
> greater than the current or a specified location (same args as break
> command) within the current frame.

Answer (score 2):

**GDB Python API**

You can run a command n times with the GDB Python API if someone really needs it:

```
class RepeatCmd(gdb.Command):
    """
    Repeat a command n times:
    repeat-cmd <n> <cmd>
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            'repeat-cmd',
            gdb.COMMAND_NONE,
            gdb.COMPLETE_NONE,
            False
        )
    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        args = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        n = int(args[0])
        cmd = ' '.join(args[1:])
        for i in range(n):
            gdb.execute(cmd)
RepeatCmd()
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/dotfiles/blob/8bd2110bcea45d61eb39ea4c185ba75b2f2cacfa/home/.gdbinit.py#L193).

For the use case, you may also be interested in [`continue <n>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956889/how-to-make-a-gdb-breakpoint-only-break-after-the-point-is-reached-a-given-numbe/46251968#46251968).